# Excel Split Single Array into Multiple Cells

Tags: arrays, excel, split, rows

An application I use exports strings of data in an array in one cell, like so:

```
"data1"= value1; "data2"= value2; "data3"= value3; "data4"= value4; "data5"= value5;
```

I'd like an equation or macro or something that could split it like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   |  data0  |  data1  |  data2 |  data3  |  data4  |  data5  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1 |  ARRAY  |  value1 | value2 |  value3 |  value4 |  value5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 |  ARRAY  |  value1 | value2 |  value3 |  value4 |  value5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 3 |  ARRAY  |  value1 | value2 |  value3 |  value4 |  value5 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
. . . . and so on.
```

Is this possible?

Here is a string from the document:

```
"search-terms1" = Chinese jade; "search-terms2" = Chinese archers; "search-terms3" = Antique jade; "search-terms4" = Asian jade; "search-terms5" = China history;
```

It will always be search-terms1 - search-terms5, but the 'values' will be different for each row.

Excel 2003 on Windows XP

Comment: The database exports thousands of rows, each with a single column containing that string. I'm just showing the layout I'm looking to accomplish with some sort of script or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will start in A2 and go down for how ever many rows have data. It's splits the values out into the columns to the right.

```
Sub SplitSearch()

    Dim vaTerms As Variant
    Dim vaSearch As Variant
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim vaOutput As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells
        vaSearch = Split(rCell.Value, ";")
        ReDim vaOutput(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(vaSearch))
        For i = LBound(vaSearch) To UBound(vaSearch)
            vaTerms = Split(vaSearch(i), "=")
            If UBound(vaTerms) > -1 Then
                vaOutput(1, i + 1) = Trim(vaTerms(UBound(vaTerms)))
            End If
        Next i
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vaOutput, 2)).Value = vaOutput
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: It's great, but I have two small issues. I'm trying to use it on a document where the column is 'AZ'. I tried to change 'A2' to 'AZ2', but I get a Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. Also, not sure if it does, but does the script ignore a row if it's empty? Just in case that's whats messing up the script.

Answer (score 1):

You you probably should do a search and replace on the complete array string, replacing the semi-colons with a linefeed, \n or vbCrLf **BEFORE** the array string is brought into excel because cell string size limits may cause truncation of your content, if you are pulling a lot of data in the string. (*Stuff may be cut off and you won't know*)

Anything less may not be correctly importing all of the results you are dealing with.

Once you replace the semi-colons with linefeeds import the text, or open the file with '=' as the delimiter

Comment: I can't do anything before it's brought into Excel. It's exported from an online application. Whatever it exports is what I get. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are saying.

Comment: is the online application creating and excel sheet for you? if it inserts everything into a single cell you risk losing data. If the export is to a format you just happen to open in excel you maybe able to manipulate it first. If it is a copy/paste of an online display you can paste into a text editor first

Comment: excel 2003 cell character limit is about 32767, 2010 seems to be the same.

Comment: Also, the cells shouldn't ever exceed more than 300 characters, if that.

Comment: then you can open the csv file in notepad and do the search/replace and it makes it really easy. I would recommend notepad++ as you can replace the ';' with '\n' and then open the file in excel, delimited with '=' and it will be exactly what you want. Even eliminate or include the first column if you like

Comment: The file actually has a ton of columns. I'm trying to make an entire macro to process this file quickly, without the need to do a ton of work. It has to be run a few times a day, and has over 300 rows and growing.

Comment: sorry I missed the earlier comment about multiple rows. vba replacing = and ; with tabs ought to do most of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string first at ";", than at "=". The code below can get you started:

```vb
Dim s As String
Dim parts As Variant
s = """data1""= value1; ""data2""= value2;"
parts = Split(s, ";")

For i = 0 To UBound(parts)
    Debug.Print parts(i)
    ' TODO: Split part along "=" and insert into cell
Next i
```

Comment: data[x] and value[x] are not as shown, they are different strings of data. This is a real string from the exported file. 

"search-terms1" = Chinese jade; "search-terms2" = Chinese archers; "search-terms3" = Antique jade; "search-terms4" = Asian jade; "search-terms5" = China history;

It will always be search-terms1 - 5, just for reference. the "values" will be different for each row.

Comment: if you want to use this, you just walk through the whole sheet and for each cell in range s=cell